# Error while running android applicaton on android devise?

Tags: android

I am developing an application in which certain images are rotated using Viewflipper. The problem is that my application is successfully running on the emulator, but it does not work when running on my actual Android device. It gives me the following error message:

```
   (The Application Package Installer (Process com.androi.packageinstaller)
       has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again).
```

What is causing this to fail when running from the device?